# PTY is not working

Tags: ssh-keys, aix

I have a problem when trying to log into a server with my ssh keys, it throws me the message: "key_load_public: invalid format PTY allocation request failed on channel 0". I try to fix this by increasing the PTY number of terminals, restarting the sshd service, killing the ssh processes, but didnt solve anything

I could connect without having to use my ssh keys, by using password authentification, this means that the issue should be in the authorized_keys file. I checked that file and found out something like this:

from="x.x.x.x",no-pty,no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa .......

Could this have something to do with me not being able to login??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, yes; the fact that the key is configured to disallow allocation of PTY will mean that no PTY allocation request will work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `no-pty` means that the user connecting with this key will not be allowed to allocate PTY (as described in the manual page for `sshd`).